# glassfish 4.1 class org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, glassfish-4

please help, this is very confusing, I can't deploy my war file in glassfish (where previously it could) with an error message like this

```
"https://localhost:4848/management/domain/applications/application/myApp"
 created successfully. Warning: Command _deploy did not complete
 successfully on server instance instance1: remote failure: Failed to
 load the application on instance instance1. The application will not
 run properly. Please fix your application and redeploy. Exception
 while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Please see
 server.log for more details. Warning: Command _deploy did not complete
 successfully on server instance instance1: remote failure: Failed to
 load the application on instance instance1. The application will not
 run properly. Please fix your application and redeploy. Exception
 while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle ....
 msg.seeServerLog
```

glassfish : 4.1

java version : 1.7.0_121

os : ubuntu server 12

I also could not find meaningful information in the server.log

but my war file can work well on my local tomcat

I'm sure there is no duplicates lib, because it was previously running well and indeed there was no change in my lib

Comment: Is this executable war file? I see tomcat logs at the end. Looks like inside glassfish war try to run tomcat.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to this question. yes this is,
you see tomcat logs at the end? what do you mean? indeed on my local pc I use eclipse + tomcat and I export to become a war file after that I deploy it to glassfish, but it usually goes smoothly so far

and one more that makes me feel very confused, the war file (the same) that I deploy does not always fail, sometimes it works sometimes it fails, with error messages like the above, bugs like this whether coming from the glassfish server or on my eclipse side when I export become a war file?